# What place for shared dependency versions in multi-module build?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multi-module SBT project where several of the subprojects depend on the same artifacts. I would like to manage the versions of these common dependencies at the root project so that I can do something like this in the subprojects (`global.SprayVersion` should come from the root project):

`libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-client"  % global.SprayVersion`

What I've tried:

- A Common.scala object at the root level which contains a `val` for each dependency
- In the root build.sbt file: `val myDepVersion = '1.0'`

Should I define new SettingKeys for each dependency? This seems a bit overkill to me. I would like to keep a bit more grouped, not polluting the setting key namespace. Also, the subprojects don't need to be able to override these values.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a sequence of dependencies, for example, in a separate object, like this:

```
object Deps {
  val akka = Seq(
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % Global.akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % Global.akkaVersion
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % Global.akkaVersion % "test"
  )
}
```

where `Global` is just an object with a number of strings in it:

```
object Global {
  val akkaVersion = "2.2.4"
}
```

Then you can just use `Deps` contents in your subprojects:

```
val project1 = Project(...)
  .settings(libraryDependencies ++= Deps.akka)

val project2 = Project(...)
  .settings(libraryDependencies ++= Deps.akka)
```

Comment: Just wondering aloud: Could turning them into traits make them any better, say `trait Global` and/or `trait Deps`?

Comment: Well, that's certainly possible, but I think that using objects and imports (if they are really needed) is better. Just a personal preference :)

Comment: This solution would have me decide on the exact dependencies of subprojects on the root project level. I would much rather have the dependencies declared in the subprojects (preferably in the build.sbt file). You say "you can just use `Deps`in your subprojects", but you're using that object in the root project to configure subprojects.

Comment: @bertvh, as far as I know, you can use root project definitions in subprojects too. So just import `Deps` in your subprojects, that's all.

Comment: Of course.. I tried using a Deps object, but forgot the import statement. Rookie mistake! Thanks

Comment: @Vladimir, just adding an `import Global` to build.sbt in a subproject doesn't work. Not sure if I'm doing this right?